# How To place 4 Div in 2x2 Passion without using table?

Tags: html, css

Hello My Requirement is to place four div in passion Given below without using table,

[image]

My 4 Div are Given below I tried to apply inline css ,but may be it was wrong .

```
<div id="dateDiv0" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;"></div>
<div id="chartDiv0" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;"></div>
<div id="dateDiv1" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;"></div>
<div id="chartDiv1" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;"></div>
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make use of a **container** div to represent rows, and consider your contained `<div>` elements to be columns.

Then you just need to apply `float: left` to your columns, and apply `clear: both` to your `.rows`:

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="dateDiv0" class="column"></div>
    <div id="chartDiv0" class="column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="dateDiv1" class="column"></div>
    <div id="chartDiv1" class="column"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you shouldn't really be using inline styles, as those have the maximum level of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), meaning that you can't overwrite them with regular selectors (unless you use an `!important` declaration). I've removed your inline styles in the above example.

Assuming you can't edit your HTML structure at all, here's an alternative solution that simply adds `clear: left` to `#dateDiv1`. Note that all four elements should `float` to the `left`! This keep the `inline` styles you've added, but I really would recommend removing them. If you do, simply remember to `float` all four elements.

```css
#dateDiv0, #chartDiv0, #dateDiv1, #chartDiv1 {
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

#dateDiv1 {
  float: left !important;
  clear: left;
}

#chartDiv1 {
  float: left !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="dateDiv0" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;"></div>
<div id="chartDiv0" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;"></div>
<div id="dateDiv1" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;"></div>
<div id="chartDiv1" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;"></div>
```

Finally, note that you have duplicate `chartDiv0` IDs, which is invalid markup. I've replaced the second with `chartDiv1` in both examples.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: CSS grid is a much better solution.

Comment: As all div are dynamically generated and i am not able to create any div or container, i can just modify their css properties.

Comment: @jhpratt -- Care to explain why?

Comment: Grid was created for 2D layouts, and eliminates the need for row containers.

Comment: @jhpratt -- I could make the same argument about flexbox. Or I could opt for a solution that works in Internet Explorer and Opera Mini - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid. That's why I went with containers. Feel free to suggest a CSS Grid alternative.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Flexbox is intended for 1D layouts, not 2D. I'm aware that grid isn't at 100% support in old browsers, but it doesn't detract from the fact that this is what it was created for.

Comment: @ChetanChaudhari -- I've updated my answer to provide a secondary solution that covers not having to change the HTML structure **at all** (including inline declarations), which also is supported in all browsers :)

Comment: And still not sure why this answer is deserving of a downvote, considering it solves the problem in two different ways, with the latter stating why it is not recommended.

Comment: Upvote to counter: this answer is perfectly valid and offers alternative solutions

Comment: @ObsidianAge wasn't from me. No reason to downvote a valid answer, I was just pointer out "newer" options exist.

Answer (score 7):

CSS grid was created exactly for situations like this.

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* set column sizes here */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto; /* we want two rows */

    grid-gap: 10px; /* how far between cells? */
    grid-auto-flow: column; /* fill in by column, not row */

    /* temporary property for visualization */
    height: 150px;
}

section div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</section>
```

To everyone suggesting flexbox, I suggest reading Rachel Andrew's blog. Grid should be used with 2D layouts, flex with 1D.

Comment: Finally, other people realising it should be `grid` in these situations! Just be mindful that this will **not** work for IE without a few alterations.

Comment: @jaunt Edge 15- and any IE. Edge 16 actually has support, and older versions can be used with prefix (older spec).

Comment: And yes, you can use it with any container, you'll just have to change the CSS selector.

Comment: you need to remove `grid-auto-flow: column;` in order to make 2x2

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section div {
  flex: 0 calc(50% - 20px); /* 50%  minus 2x 10px margin */
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box; /*so the value of border counts in width/height*/
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Or CSS GRID

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

section div {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a margin without using calc? Seems like a waste to [reduce browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) just for that

Comment: there is, just using a less percentage instead of 50%, use something like 40% alone without `calc`, but this way is accurate. That's why I used it